# How to check if FirebaseAnimatedList returns data in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I need to show another widget if FirebaseAnimatedList query not return any data, so not only show blank screen, how can I do this?

I am using

```
if(snapshot.value != null){} and if(!snapshot.exists()) {}
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the size of the list of documents.

For example:

```
 //check in Firebase - Realtime Database
 final FirebaseDatabase _database = FirebaseDatabase(app: FirebaseApp.instance);
 void checkEmptyList() async {
    var data = await _database.reference().child('your_child').once();
    if (data.value == null) {
      //document without data
    } else {
      //document with data
    }
  }

  //check in Firebase - Cloud Firestore
  final Firestore _fireStore = Firestore.instance;
  void checkEmptyList() async {
    var doc = await _fireStore.collection("your_collections").getDocuments();
    if (doc.documents.isEmpty) {
      //document without data
    } else {
      //document with data
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I am using Firebase Realtime database, the method is the same?

Comment: thank you very much for your help it worked perfect!